# How to change position of a an icon inside a combobox in html?

Tags: css, html

I have a search box on page and there is an icon on that box which I found sample code for the icon.

[image]

But I want to put that icon to the right of the combo box. I have played around *style* but I could not achieve to position icon to right.

Can you help me?

My code is:

```
<mat-form-field class="search">
          <div class="icon-div">
            <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
          </div>
          <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search office">
</mat-form-field>
```

and my style file is:

```
.search {
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.search input {
  text-indent: 4px;
}

.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.icon-div {
  padding-top: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Is moving the `input` before the `icon-div` an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.search .fa-search {
  right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are less valued. Kindly add some explanation as to what your code is doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The CSS in the answer doesn't appear to address the enclosing `<div>` around the span.fa-search. So while it would set `right` to zero for the span, it wouldn't move the div in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Swap `left` for `right`

```
.search .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.search {
  position: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Position center values is invalid property value. To achieve the position icon right please change this below property to

```
position: relative;
```